# Dynamically get a variable (from a string) in Jinja

Tags: templates, dynamic, get, jinja2

My Jinja top-level context has variables defined in sequence like `foo_0`, `foo_1`, etc.

I'd like to be able to access those variables dynamically by generating strings with code like `"foo_" + str(0)`.

If effect, I want to do something like `{{ eval("foo_0") }}` in my Jinja template, and access those variables in sequence.

Is this possible?

Note: I'm using a cloud service I don't control (which provides Jinja templating), so:

- I can't use data structures in the Jinja context (all variable values must be strings).
- I can't customize the Jinja runtime environment or add filters. But it would be helpful to know if this can be solved by adding a custom filter.

Comment: This problem is really irking me! The "all variables must be strings" is really what's getting to me. If you could just pass in one function with the [`contextfunction`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.contextfunction) decorator, this would be simple!

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to find a standard/documented way to do this but through poking around:

```
In [30]: Template("{{ self._TemplateReference__context.resolve('foo_0')  }}").render(foo_0='this_is_foo_0', foo_1='this_is_foo_1')
Out[30]: 'this_is_foo_0'
```

Comment: I haven't tested, but `vars['foo' + str(0)]` should work.

Comment: @Arnaud answer is tested and valid in an Ansible template